# numpy.test('full') FAILED on Mac OS 10.10.4

Tags: python, macos, testing, numpy

This is the environment of python2.7.10 on my Max OS 10.10.4

```
/usr/bin$ python2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 17 2015, 13:55:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And when I run the testing of numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.test('full')
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.9.2
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.10 (default, Sep 17 2015, 13:55:58) [GCC 4.2.1       Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]
nose version 1.3.7
```

And the final result is that the test failed, but I don't know why even after I searched on Stack Overflow:

```
Ran 5430 tests in 78.141s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=14, SKIP=39, errors=6, failures=18)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=5430 errors=6 failures=18>
```

So can anyone tell me how to correct those failures as I don't want such failures to interfere my work. Thanks in advance.:)